# How do I position/align a markdown table in a revealjs Quarto doc?

Tags: reveal.js, quarto

How do I specify right vs. left. vs. center alignment/justification for a markdown table in a revealjs Quarto doc?

I am thinking it should be something like this:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: revealjs
editor: visual
---


## Eating

::: {.align="right"}
| Food   | Ranking |
| ------ | ------- |
| coffee |  9 |
| nachos | 10 |
| kale   |  2 |
:::
```

Answer (score 0):

For center (which is I think the default anyways) you can use the predefined `.center` class, e.g.

```
---
format: revealjs
---

## Eating

::: {.center}
| Food   | Ranking |
| ------ | ------- |
| coffee |  9 |
| nachos | 10 |
| kale   |  2 |
:::
```

For right and left alignment I would use the `.column` class:

```
---
format: revealjs
---
  
## Eating 2

:::: {.columns}

::: {.column width="50%"}
| Food   | Ranking |
| ------ | ------- |
| coffee |  9 |
| nachos | 10 |
| kale   |  2 |
:::
::: {.column width="50%"}
| Food   | Ranking |
| ------ | ------- |
| coffee |  9 |
| nachos | 10 |
| kale   |  2 |
:::
::::
```